# How to convert custom nested list xml to respective java object

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have below XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<objectWithList>
    <MyList>
        <abc>hi</abc>
        <list>Somewhere</list>
        <list>This and that</list>
        <list>Something</list>
    </MyList>
</objectWithList>
```

which I want to convert to java object using jaxb unmarshaller.

Java File for xml mapping-

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ObjectWithList {
    @XmlElement
    private String abc;
    private List<String> list;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="MyList")
    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

main driver class code for conversion -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectWithList.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ObjectWithList emps = (ObjectWithList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("c:/emp.xml"));
        for (String s : emps.getList()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

but this  is not working. I am getting the below exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/c:/emp.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at com.netspend.idology.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/c:/emp.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
```

This problem has taken my whole day. 
Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that you're reading the correct file and that there's nothing before the `<?xml` ?

Comment: OMG. I didn't have idea that space before <?xml> will cause issue. I corrected the xml and got the code working. now no exception. But main problem after this was that only list was getting populated not the <abc> tag, it was coming null. Below answer by @sambit works fine. Thanks for sharing info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the modified program which works. Also you have to understand about the usage of structure of class and the use of annotation at proper places.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement
public class ObjectWithList {

  private MyList myList;

  @XmlElement(name = "MyList")
  public MyList getMyList() {
    return myList;
  }

  public void setMyList(MyList myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ObjectWithList{" + "myList=" + myList + '}';
  }
}



import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "MyList")
public class MyList {

  private String abc;

  private List<String> list;

  @XmlElement(name = "abc")
  public String getAbc() {
    return abc;
  }

  public void setAbc(String abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "list")
  public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
  }

  public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MyList{" + "abc='" + abc + '\'' + ", list=" + list + '}';
  }
}



import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectWithList.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    ObjectWithList emps =
        (ObjectWithList)
            jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(
                new File("D:/someFolder/emp.xml"));
    for (String s : emps.getMyList().getList()) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(emps);
    System.out.println(" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo very much @Sambit .  It worked. You are right, I have to brush up the info about tags.

Comment: Could you please mark it as Answered and Accepted ?

Comment: can you please take a look at related question also -

Comment: Can you please take a look at related question also - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276338/autmapping-of-xml-list-of-string-response-by-rest-service-to-respective-java-obj