# Autmapping of xml list of string response by rest service to respective java object using RestTemplate.postForObject(.....)

Tags: jackson, jaxb, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller, jackson-databind

I have below XML which I am getting from third party(rest service)

```
<response>
<error>Document Too Small</error>
<error>Barcode Not Detected</error>
<error>Face Image Not Detected</error>
</response>
```

I am calling third party service with below code which is trying to convert the xml to respective java object -

```
restTemplate.postForObject("/test", new HttpEntity<>(request, headers), Eror.class);
```

We have added the MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter-

```
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

Below is the Eror.class code -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Eror {
    private List<String> error;

    public List<String> getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(List<String> error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

The same code works fine if we have simple types like string, int but issue comes when we have list of string.
I get the following exception -

```
 Exception cause - 
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token
```

FYI if I did manual parsing from xml to respective java using jaxb marshaller like below then it worked properly -

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Eror.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Eror err = (Eror) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("c:/error.xml"));
```

Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am still unable to understand the problem, Once I get, I will help you. Can you tell me the exact problem, as I see you have already written the jaxb unmarshaller.

Comment: jaxb unmarshaller is the one way where I can convert xml to java object. When we're working on rest services then resttemplate provides facility to do this job automatically. Here I am unable to convert the list of xml elements to respective java object. I hope it'll help.

Comment: I got it, you want MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter to convert the object automatically right ?

Comment: Yes. that's what I want

Comment: Ok, I will help you to solve.

Comment: What is the web mvc version are you using ?

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml file here ?

Comment: actually it's not the web-mvc but spring-boot rest service.It's gradle project and has so many dependencies. May I know which specific dependency you are looking for..

some related to this code  -- 
compile(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.4')
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.10'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.10'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193864/discussion-between-arvind-maurya-and-sambit).

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use Jaxb for xml for marshalling and unmarshalling. Still if you want to use, jackson way of doing. You have to do in the following manner.

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
String xmlString = "your xml response";

try {
     Eror eror = mapper.readValue(xmlString, Eror.class);
     System.out.println("eror = " + eror);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

For better understanding its usage, refer below the links.
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-requestbody-responsebody-example/

https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-xml-response-example-with-jackson-2

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: thanks for the reply but it's not helping me. Actually with existing configuration, i am able to parse the other xml like <response><name>Arvind</name></response>. But the problem is with list as i have given in question.

Comment: I think, there should be another root element for error, because you are getting repeated error details.

Comment: Are you getting the same response from third party ? Can you share the uri to test ?

Comment: yes sure. -- the uri to get the response - http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ce6c8e33300001d81731845